# How to send data to php file api using http post with same key but multiple value?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I want to **send multiple value** with **same key** from flutter/dart to php api using http POST. But i dont know how to do that. I have been searching for the past few days but still can't find the answer. What is in my mind is something like this:

```
    void changeStatus(){
      var url = "http://url";
      http.post(url, body: json.encode({
        "id": ["31","32"]
      }));
    }
```

And in the php file look like this :

```
$id = array();
    for( $i=0 ; $i < count($_POST['id']) ; $i++ )
    {
        $id[$i]['id'] = $_POST['id'][$i];

    }

    for( $i=0 ; $i < count($_POST['id']) ; $i++ )
    {
        $queryResult = $connect->query("UPDATE someTable SET someField = 'yes' WHERE idField ($id[$i]['id'])");

    }
```

**The code above is just what I imagined**, because I don't know how it should be implemented in the code. So if anyone understands how to do that, it will be very helpful

Comment: You can have multiple fields named `id[]` and it you will have a POST param `id` as an array of values. Like `curl <url> -d "id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3" `. In the server, the param `id` will be `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: if u dont mind, can u please show me how to implement that in code example?

Comment: @MaruziMuslih have a look at my answer, and let me know the result. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer Omar, but unexpectedly I have found a way to do it haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can figure it out. Idk if it's the best solution or not, but for me it works. I just need to loop the http.post like this:

```
void changeStatus(){
    List listId = ["31","32"];
    var url = "http://url";
    for (var i = 0; i < listId.length; i++) {
    http.post(url, body: {
        "id": listId[i],
      });
    }
  }
```

Then in the php file just like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$queryResult = $connect->query("UPDATE someTable SET someField = 'yes' WHERE idField = '".$id."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these ids to the PHP page using ajax call where your id needed to perform query operations.

```
<script>
      function changeStatus(){
                    
                    var url = "http://localhost/update.php";
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        id: ["31","32"],
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        //here you can get response if you send from php-end
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        //do something on error
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        //do something on complete
                    }
                });
            }
      </script>
```

Now in `update.php` file

```
    $ids = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : [];

    foreach( $ids as $id )
    {
        $queryResult = $connect->query("UPDATE someTable SET someField = 'yes' WHERE idField $id");
    
    }
```